# problem with javascript reading text of docx

Tags: javascript

I am uploading file and extracting it's content and putting into a textarea. I can successfully work with txt files but for docx files, it does not work well.

my code:

```
 function loadFileAsText(){
  var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];

  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent){
      var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
      document.getElementById("inputTag").value = textFromFileLoaded;
  };

   fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "ANSI");
}
```

When I am trying to upload docx files ,it gives something like this :

```
PK     ! ߤ�lZ      [Content_Types].xml �(�                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ���n�0E�����Ub袪*�>�-R�{V��Ǽ��QU�
l"%3��3Vƃ�ښ
```

Am I missing a decoding part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't achieve it your way. You must use dedicated library to read `docx` files. If you run `docx` file in notepad you see that it's not plain text, because you have all additional data, meta data etc. in this file.

Examples:

[get docx file contents using javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440170/get-docx-file-contents-using-javascript-jquery)

[JavaScript library to read doc and docx on client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44698896/javascript-library-to-read-doc-and-docx-on-client)

Answer (score 0):

.docx sligtly coplicated that regular text file, exactly, is a ZIP archive of numbers of  XML files.

There are could be a gotachas, even if you successfuly unarchive docx, it still unclear which of the XML file from it you should parse and attempt to interpret as text.

in all cases when I needed to do something similar, I used server solutions, my own or third parties, and there were always problems with the conversion.